# Some $(document).ready() code is ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some js to change the width of a span based on the width of an element with the class '.line'. I put this in a function line() with a parameter color. If I call the function from the console it works, but in `$(document).ready()` it's ignored. Other calls in `$(document).ready()` do work. Do you guys have any idea where it goes wrong?

**`$(document).ready()`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    line("rood");
});
```

**`line(color)`**

```
function line(color){
  var primeWidth = $(".container-inhoud")[0].offsetWidth;
  if (color === "rood"){
    text = $('.rood .line')[0].offsetWidth;
    span = $('.rood .line span');
    count = primeWidth - text - 45;
    $('.rood .line span').css("width", count);
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="rood">
 <h2 class="line">Je blinkt uit in<span></span></h2>
 <ul>
   <li>Vrijheid in gedachten, woord en daad</li>
   <li>Een heldere geest</li>
   <li>Aanpassingsvermogen en begrip voor anderen</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

You can also find an example page at: https://test.flowzo.nl/getal-5/

Comment: When and where do you declare `function line`? Is it possible, that it isn't ready yet?

Comment: +1 @Zim84. Also, are all the elements you target in your `line` function already created or are they dynamically added to the DOM ?

Comment: +1 VaILeNain. Also, you're stating that "it's ignored". Are you sure? Have you tried `console.log("test")` inside your `line()` function? This way you know whether the function is actually ignored (what I think does not happen without some error or warning) or, as VaILeNain states, part of the function are not yet ready for execution, since not all of the needed elements are in DOM already.

Comment: @Zim84 It should be ready, as I'm not using JS anywhere to add elements to the DOM. Just html/php. I added reference HTML to the question and a link to a page the code is on. - I added a "the function is called" console.log, which only get's displayed after calling it manually.

Comment: There's an error message in the console. The script throws an error earlier so the execution never reaches the document.ready code.

Comment: @JJJ You are right, I forgot that Gulp concatenates all the JS... Thanks for the help!